# Magento - Disable customer of Changing / Reset email

Tags: email, magento-1.7, reset

For security reasons I need to disable the possibility in form the user to change his email. Once set it can't be change. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we had an extension that override the user model/controller/view, example: social login, and because we decided not to use it we Disable it in the advanced settings.

Because it was disable, the list of users was not showing in the back-end, but I could create a new customer, yet in the New customer view the Addresses were not showing either.

So, we activated all the extensions again and suddenly the customers list appears. So like this we found out which extension was breaking and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8622/

Maybe usefull for someone ...

Comment: Links don't make good answers because they go stale. Try to include the relevant info IN your answer.

Comment: The problem was that an extension whas OVERRIDING the customers model and I had it disable in the advanced settings.

Comment: I come here in 2023 and the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

In `template/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml`

```
<div class="inner-head">
        <h5><?php echo $this->__('Contact Information') ?></h5>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/edit') ?>">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getFirstname()) ?> 
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getLastname()) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?><br />
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getChangePasswordUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?></a>
    </p>
```

and Replace with:

```
<div class="inner-head">
        <h5><?php echo $this->__('Contact Information') ?></h5><br />

    </div>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getFirstname()) ?> 
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getLastname()) ?><br />
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getChangePasswordUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?></a>
    </p>
```

Extracted and adapted from the [magento community forums](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8622/).

Answer (score -1):

In file :
app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php

```
/**
     * Change customer password action
     */
    public function editPostAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/edit');
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setId($this->_getSession()->getCustomerId())
                ->setWebsiteId($this->_getSession()->getCustomer()->getWebsiteId());

            $fields = Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('customer_account');
            $data = $this->_filterPostData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

            //=========
           // ADD THAT // customer cannot change his email // Le customer ne peut pas modifier son email
            if(isset($data['email'])){
                $data['email'] = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer()->getData('email');
            }
            //========END   

            foreach ($fields as $code=>$node) {
                if ($node->is('update') && isset($data[$code])) {
                    $customer->setData($code, $data[$code]);
                }
            }

            $errors = $customer->validate();
            if (!is_array($errors)) {
                $errors = array();
            }
```

Comment: Just FYI, for anyone reading this answer. You should never modify a core file that way.